# Program Highlightning .clp files?

Tags: jess, clp

I am developing an expert system using Jess shell.
I would like a program so as to highlight with colors my code because I 
want to paste it in a word document.

Is there extension in notepad++ ??
Or another program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Plugin for TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/add-ons/files/syntax/jess.zip), [JESS mode for GNU EMACS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jess-mode/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm later, but maybe could be usefull

in vim just type `:set filetype=jess`
in Notepad++ I tried to make my own with [this xml](http://pastebin.com/tuKQyBTN)

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple more listed [here:](http://www.jessrules.com/contributions/) the ones in @c69's answer, plus ones for jEdit and EditPlus.

Answer (score -1):

There is also an Eclipse plugin that comes with Jess71p2 version. You just have to copy paste the content of the eclipse folder from that Jess version and restart eclipse. Any .clp files will be opened with the Jess Editor plugin. :)